# location.reload() make a difference with my DB

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I realized a code for a rate system but when I select a vote, nothing change, when I reselect again a vote, it's ok ! BUT when I see my DB on phpmyadmin, the counter of vote has 1 clic in more than the counter of vote that I "echoed" on my page... why this difference of 1?

my note.js

```
$(function(){
    $('.star').on('mouseover', function(){
        var indice = $('.star').index(this);
        $('.star').removeClass('full');
        for(var i = 0; i<= indice; i++){
            $('.star:eq('+i+')').addClass('full');  
        }
    }); 

    $('.star').on('mouseout', function(){
        $('.star').removeClass('full');
        });

    var average = $('.average').attr('data-average');
    function avaliacao(average){
        average = (Number(average)*20);
        $('.barra .bg').css('width', 0);
        $('.barra .bg').animate({width: average+'%'}, 500);
    }
    avaliacao(average);


    $('.star').on('click', function(){
        var artigoId = $('.artigoDados').attr('data-id');
        var ponto = $(this).attr('id');
        location.reload();
        $.post('sys/votar.php',{votar: 'sim', artigo: artigoId, ponto: ponto}, function(retorno){
        avaliacao(retorno.average);
        $('p.votos span').html(retorno.votos);

        }, 'jSON');

    });

});
```

My html code:

```
<?php 

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notation', 'root', 'root');

?>

<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/note.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<?php
    $artigoId = (int)$_GET['artigo'];

    $artigos = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM sys_note WHERE id_recette = ?');
    $artigos->execute(array($artigoId));
    while($row = $artigos->fetchObject()){
    echo '<h1>'.$row->titre_recette.'</h1>';
    $calculo = ($row->pontos == 0) ? 0 : round(($row->pontos/$row->votos), 1);
    echo '<span class="average" data-average="'.$calculo.'"></span>';
    echo '<span class="artigoDados" data-id="'.$row->id_recette.'"></span>';




?>

<div class="barra">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <div class="estrelas">
    <?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++): ?>
    <span class ="star" id="<?php echo $i;?>">
    <span class="starAbsolute"></span>
    </span>
    <?php endfor;?>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="votos"><span><?php echo $row->votos;?></span>votes</p>
<?php }?>

</body>
</html>
```

**votar.php**

```
<?php 

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notation', 'root', 'root');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $artigo = (int)$_POST['artigo'];    
    $pontos = $_POST['ponto'];

    $pegaArtigo = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM sys_note WHERE id_recette = ?');
    $pegaArtigo->execute(array($artigo));

    while($row = $pegaArtigo->fetchObject()){
        $votosUpd = $row->votos+1;
        $pontosUpd = $row->pontos+$pontos;
        $average = round(($pontosUpd/$votosUpd), 1);
        $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE sys_note SET votos = ?, pontos = ? WHERE id_recette = ?');
        if($update->execute(array($votosUpd, $pontosUpd, $artigo))){
        die(json_encode(array('average' => $average, 'votos' => $votosUpd)));   

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: why do you need to reload the page at all? Defeats the purpose of using ajax

Comment: @charlietfl I have a system of notation and when I choose my vote, I want the result been actualize on the clic

Comment: right...and that's why you are using ajax

Comment: I'm wrong? Do u know how to resolve my problem? @charlietfl

Comment: get rid of `location.reload();`

Comment: ok but when I get ride of location.reload(), there is no actualisation..

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: If I cancel location.reload(); when I select a vote, I must refresh the page. But me, I want the refresh automatically when I voted

Comment: do u know how to help me please @charlietfl ?

Comment: don't understand why you need a refresh, can simply update the vote counter

Comment: how to update automatically? It's better for the user to show the average after his vote

Answer (score 0):

You need to do  location.reload(); after you the post, not before.

```
$.post('sys/votar.php',{votar: 'sim', artigo: artigoId, ponto: ponto}, function(retorno){
    location.reload();
    }, 'jSON');
```

There is no point to do the extra work inside the callback since you are reloading the page anyway.
Although, I would recommend you change the elements on the page via ajax instead of the crude location.reload();

Comment: I'm not sure to be know how to do with the second solution..
And I did like you wrote, but nothing changed..

Comment: can u explain me better please @albattran ?